# Eclipse does not recognize package Import? JOGL

Tags: java, eclipse, jogl

i have jogl in the path and this program works fine until i include "import net.java.games.jogl.*;" on the top of the code. I get error "Import cannot be resolved" As i told you it works without the import. The Native Libraries are installed and jogl.jar is installed. Why isnt Eclipse recognizing this package import?  here is the code:

```
import net.java.games.jogl.*;
public class HelloWorld
    { // open HelloWorld

        public static void main(String[] args)
        { // open main
            try
            { // open try
                System.loadLibrary("jogl");
                System.out.println("Hello World! (The native libraries are installed.)");
            } // close try
            catch (Exception e) // all try's need a catch
            { } // even if the catch does nothing
        } // close main

    } // close HelloWorld
```

Comment: Not all `try`'s need a `catch`.  Some do just fine with only a `finally`...

Comment: thats not an answer to my question...

Comment: This is not where we answer questions.  This is where we comment.

Comment: Well in that case, theres nothing wrong with including a catch

Comment: I think he's just commenting on your comment "all try's need a catch". Anyway, have you tried `import javax.media.opengl.*`?

Comment: Why don't you use a class you know is in the jar and see what import Eclipse tries? As Jiahua alluded too, perhaps you have the wrong import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the example you are working from is using an outdated package name.  Take a look at the contents of the jar to determine the correct package.

This [link (from 2006)](http://processing.org/discourse/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1159148966) is suggesting you may want to look at the package `javax.media.opengl`.  Also, here is some [javadoc for jogl](http://download.java.net/media/jogl/jogl-2.x-docs/) that I found.  I am not sure how up to date it is though...

Comment: I get no option to add to build path only to remove it from build path. Therefore we already know that it is already included in the build path. Any other ideas?

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I was unaware that they updated packages lol :P

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are using Maven or not but check your Java Build Path from inside Eclipse. Under Libraries tab ensure that JOGL is listed.